# Need suggestions on best approach to update text entered into multiple textboxes without causing a postback that shifts the page

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, visual-studio-2008, textbox

This is a concept question.  I have a web form with 6 gridviews, below each gridview is a textbox. Each row of the gridview contains a question and 5 radio buttons. When a radio button is ticked or text is entered in the textbox it updates the database immediately with one caveat, the textbox is committed when the user presses the tab key, or refocuses curser outside the textbox, or clicks an unrelated button (basically when a postback or textchanged() event occurs).

The problem: There is a delay during postback when the text is committed to the database causing the user to think they can move to the next textbox only to have the curser return to the previous textbox.  I added code to prevent the curser jumping but the delay is still an annoyance to users during testing. I added a confirmation message (label) to alert the user when it's ok to move on but when the confirmation message disappears at the next postback, usually when the user ticks the next radio button, the gridview shifts up and the user's curser is pointed to a different line of the grid.  This is also annoying users.

Solutions? In my limited experience I have 2 alternatives maybe 3 (below). The reason I did not do either was because I wanted data to update the database as soon as it was typed or ticked.  Since the radio buttons cause an immediate update I didn't want the users to inadvertently think the textboxes did too   and forget to click a button to commit the text. Since entering text in the textboxes is optional, I don't have a way to validate if the user is done completing the form and remind them to click a button to commit their text input.

1. Put a button by each textbox to commit the text
2. Use one button to commit all textbox data when form is complete
3. Find a way to put a placeholder where the confirmation label is when its hidden so it doesn't shift on postback.

I'm starting to think one Submit button is the way to go and let the user think that is what saves the data? Simple.

At any rate is there a better way to achieve my goals of having input updated in database immediately without annoying delays (postbacks) and grid shifting at inopportune times?

Comment: May be try html5 and service worker..
https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/forms/html5forms/
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/

Comment: My app is for browser from Windows PC user.  Your solution seemed more appropriate for mobile devices. I appreciate the pointer though - something new I didn't know about.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I changed the textbox `AutoPostBack` property to `False` and removed all code in the `text_changed()` event for all textboxes. I am committing the text when a Submit button is clicked. (The radio buttons still commit to db immediately when selected).  In the end, I think users are conditioned to click a submit or save button when they finish filling out a form anyway.